# Monitor enters standby mode on windows 7 startup screen - functions normally in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display, nvidia-graphics-card, dvi

Recently when I try to boot my desktop PC I see the BIOS post tests then the Windows Is Starting screen and then my monitor shows 'no video input' error message and goes to standby mode.

The Monitor is a Hanns-G LCD panel connected to an Asus nVidia GTX650ti via DVI-D cable. I have tried changing the DVI socket on the graphics card the cable is connected to and connecting with a VGA cable instead (this model monitor doesn't support HDMI, I'm looking at upgrading but need my computer working in the meantime) with no effect.

When I boot in safe mode everything works as it should suggesting a software problem so I ran Windows Startup Repair from the Windows Install Disk - again no result.

I've tried reinstalling the latest drivers and rolling back to older versions of the drivers with no effect. I can still only boot in safe mode. I have found that if I go into device manager and completely uninstall the display adaptor then I can boot in normal mode but windows then automatically detects the device and installs the latest drivers then asks to restart and I get the same problem on the restart.

Does anyone have any ideas before I resort to reinstalling windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when turning on my machine today. It was booting fine except that I had no video (I heard the startup sound and it would shut down fine). I could boot into safe mode but not VGA mode. I found that after disabling the display adapter my machine would boot normally.

My machine is running Win 7 Pro with an ATI video card.

The only change to the machine since the last successful boot was update KB2993651 which seems to have been causing issues in a small number of machines.

To fix it I tried:

1. Remove latest windows update KB2993651 (did not work)
2. System Restore to a variety of different points (did not work, so I reinstated the most recent)
3. Un-installing video driver and installed an older version (did work)

Since then I re-installed the latest version of the video driver and the windows update and it all works fine. So I would recommend checking to see if you have just installed that update and try re-installing it (combined with your video drivers).

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked. I was worried I'd have to completely rebuild my machine when I'm just about to upgrade to Windows 8.1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is one of two things:

Since you've already tried plugging it into the different outputs and ruled that out, the only thing left is that Windows is possibly not detecting the native resolution of the display properly and is using a resolution that is too high for the monitor to display.

Do an F8 boot of Windows, but do not choose safe mode.  Instead, choose VGA mode.  This will boot Windows normally but set it to the lowest possible resolution.  See if you have the same issue.  Once you can see the screen, you can change to the settings that work for you.  VGA mode is not safe mode, so you shouldn't be restricted in what settings you can tweak.